# Second WP_Query loop shows data from main query

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop

I am trying to show the featured posts in my theme, with a custom field `mytheme_featured_post` which is 1 on the featured posts.

However it does not seem to filter the posts down to only the posts in the meta query.

```
// WP_Query arguments.
$featured = array(
'posts_per_page' => '5',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'mytheme_featured_post',
        'value'   => '1',
    ),
),
);

// The Query.
$featured_query = new WP_Query( $featured );

if ( $featured_query -> have_posts() ) {
    while ( $featured_query -> have_posts() ) : $featured_query -> the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
}
```

**Update:**
This args are working as intended:

```
// WP_Query arguments.
$featured = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'cat'            => '1',
    'meta_key'       => 'mytheme_featured_post',
    'meta_value'     => '1',
);
```

Comment: What does it show? Does it show the data from previous query?

Comment: Seems to be the main query which displays, @JackJohansson.

Comment: Check your theme's `functions.php` file for any `pre_get_posts` filter. It might be messing with your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tricked by sticky posts. Here is the working code if anyone coming by for the same problem! Check if it works after excluding the stickies.

```
/**
 * WP_Query arguments.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
 */
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'mytheme_featured_post',
            'value'   => '1',
            ),
            ),
    );

// The Query.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your query current or not.

Ref - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

After or before every custom query, write query reset function.

```
wp_reset_query()
```

Try it.

Comment: You don't need that before and after every custom query, you only need it after overwriting the global $wp_query variable. Look at the source code and see what it actually does.

Comment: Does `get_posts()` alter the main query data? I had a custom `get_posts()` in my template, and after pulling my hairs out for a week I noticed that because I'm not using `wp_reset_postdata()` it's messing with my query. @Milo

Comment: @JackJohansson If you use `setup_postdata()` or `$query->the_post()` then you need `wp_reset_postdata()` after to restore the global `$post`. `wp_reset_query()` also works in this case because it calls `wp_reset_postdata()`, but it also restores `$wp_query`, which may have unwanted side-effects if that's not what you're expecting.